# Jquery animate till a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code for moving the `product-details-content` div by `100%` every time I click on `product-prev-button`. This code works fine except for it keeps scrolling forever. I want it to stop scrolling when the `marginLeft` is more than `-400%`. Can I introduce a condition somewhere to get it working?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#product-prev-button").click(function(){
        $("#product-details-content").animate({
            marginLeft: '-=100%'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter...

```
var MAX_CLICKS = 4;

$(function() {
    var clickCounter = 0;

    $("#product-prev-button").click(function() {
        // only move -100% if we are under or at 4 clicks (-400%)
        if (++clickCounter <= MAX_CLICKS) {
            $("#product-details-content").animate({
                marginLeft: '-=100%'
            });
        }

        // do other stuff regardless ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I'm on that ES6 hype sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("#product-prev-button").click(function(){
             var value = parseInt($("#product-details-content").css('margin-left'));                                  
             console.log(value);
             if(value > -400)
             {
                $("#product-details-content").animate({
                    marginLeft: '-=100%'
                });
             }

            });               
        });
```

Comment: By default, .animate runs for 400ms so when you click first time it's setting the margin to less then -400% it self. so second time if condition is failing. To test it set the initial margin-left value to somewhere higher like 2000 and see the animation stopping till it reaches, animation won't stop in between the values, as it happens in steps so it will complete the step and that step could set the margin-left to less then -400%

Comment: Or reduce the animation value to bring -400 in one go it self .. assuming initial margin is 0, set  marginLeft: '-=30%' which will take it to -405 .. closest to what you need.

Comment: I think what is happening to the code above is: the value of variable 'value' is in px not %. And so 'value > -400' is not working.

Comment: No, i have used "parseInt" so that's not the issue, or it would be better if you can paste your complete HTML here for better details or share your code.

Comment: I don't know if I am wrong but I think parseInt just gives the integer value. So "var value = parseInt($("#product-details-content").css('margin-left'));" is just giving the value like 600(for 600px). Its not accepting the left margin in %.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working by doing slight modicifation to the code provided by "MGA".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#product-prev-button").click(function(){
    var prevvalue1 = parseInt($("#product-details-content").css('margin-left'));
    var prevvalue2 = parseInt($("#product-details-content").outerWidth());
    var prevvalue=-(prevvalue1/prevvalue2);
    if(prevvalue < .75)
    {
        $("#product-details-content").animate({
        marginLeft: '-=100%'
         });
     }
 });
```

});